# Python asyncio wait_for synchronous

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, sleep

Using Python 3.6.8

```
async def sleeper():
    time.sleep(2)

async def asyncio_sleeper():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

await asyncio.wait_for(sleeper(), 1)

await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio_sleeper(), 1)
```

Using time.sleep does NOT timeout, asyncio.sleep does timeout.

My intuition was that calling wait_for on a coroutine would base its timeout on how long the coroutine takes, not based on the individual async calls within the coroutine.
What is going on behind the scenes that results in this behavior, and is there a way to modify behavior to match my intuition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is going on behind the scenes that results in this behavior

The simplest answer is that asyncio is based on *cooperative* multitasking, and `time.sleep` doesn't cooperate. `time.sleep(2)` blocks the thread for two seconds, the event loop and all, and there is nothing anyone can do about it.

On the other hand, `asyncio.sleep` is carefully [written](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/12695f4c6d1167c0863098a586f3dfeb77a7cb9a/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L623) so that when you `await asyncio.sleep(2)`, it immediately suspends the current task and arranges with the event loop to resume it 2 seconds later. Asyncio's "sleeping" is implicit, which allows the event loop to proceed with other tasks while the coroutine is suspended. The same suspension system allows `wait_for` to cancel the task, which the event loop accomplishes by "resuming" it in such await that the `await` where it was suspended raises an exception.

In general, a coroutine not awaiting anything is good indication that it's incorrectly written and is a coroutine in name only. Awaits are the reason coroutines exist, and `sleeper` doesn't contain any.

> is there a way to modify behavior to match my intuition?

If you must call legacy blocking code from asyncio, use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor). You will have to tell asyncio when you do so and allow it to execute the actual blocking call, like this:

```
async def sleeper():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, 2)
```

`time.sleep` (or other blocking function) will be handed off to a separate thread, and `sleeper` will get suspended, to be resumed when `time.sleep` is done. Unlike with `asyncio.sleep()`, the blocking `time.sleep(2)` will still get called and block its thread for 2 seconds, but that will not affect the event loop, which will go about its business similar to how it did when `await asyncio.sleep()` was used.

Note that cancelling a coroutine that awaits `run_in_executor` will only cancel the waiting for the blocking `time.sleep(2)` to complete in the other thread. The blocking call will continue executing until completion, which is to be expected since there is no general mechanism to interrupt it.

Comment: Nowadays you should be using asyncio.to_thread