# How to run the whole async function in given timeout?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

From the [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74652408/10969942), the duplicate post cannot answer my question.

Right now, I have a function `f1()` which contains CPU intensive part and async IO intensive part. Therefore `f1()` itself is an `async function`. **How can I run the whole `f1()` with given timeout?** I found the method provided in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61876399/10969942) cannot solve my situation. For the following part, it shows `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'f1' was never awaited handle = None  # Needed to break cycles when an exception occurs.`

```py
import asyncio
import time
import concurrent.futures

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(1)


async def f1():
    print("start sleep")
    time.sleep(3)  # simulate CPU intensive part
    print("end sleep")

    print("start asyncio.sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)  # simulate IO intensive part
    print("end asyncio.sleep")


async def process():
    print("enter process")
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(executor, f1)


async def main():
    print("-----f1-----")
    t1 = time.time()
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(process(), timeout=2)
    except:
        pass
    t2 = time.time()
    print(f"f1 cost {(t2 - t1)} s")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

From previous post, [loop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) **can only work for normal function not async function.**

Comment: You need to run the CPU-intensive part with `run_in_execturo`, not the whole coroutine. Furthermore, if the code is CPU-intensive, you need to run it inside a `ProcessPoolExecutor`. By default (i.e., when you pass `None`) it uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (or in your case where you explicitly create one).

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to make `process` not an async function, so it can run in another thread, and have it start an asyncio loop in the other thread to run f1.

note that starting another loops means you cannot share coroutines and futures between the two loops.

```py
import asyncio
import time
import concurrent.futures

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(1)


async def f1():
    print("start sleep")
    time.sleep(3)  # simulate CPU intensive part
    print("end sleep")

    print("start asyncio.sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)  # simulate IO intensive part
    print("end asyncio.sleep")


def process():
    print("enter process")
    asyncio.run(asyncio.wait_for(f1(),2))

async def main():
    print("-----f1-----")
    t1 = time.time()
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        await loop.run_in_executor(executor, process)
    except:
        pass
    t2 = time.time()
    print(f"f1 cost {(t2 - t1)} s")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

```py
-----f1-----
enter process
start sleep
end sleep
start asyncio.sleep
f1 cost 3.0047199726104736 s
```

keep in mind that you must wait for any IO to return f1 to the eventloop so the future can be cancelled, you cannot cancel the CPU-intensive part of the code unless it does something like `await asyncio.sleep(0)` which returns to the event-loop momentarily, which is why `time.sleep` cannot be cancelled.

Comment: In your code, the f1 cost `3s`. However, I want to stop after `2s`.

Comment: @maplemaple you can't .... python itself isn't running during that time, and the OS isn't servicing the thread on any core. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread

Comment: @maplemaple you should probably either implement a kill switch that is periodically checked ... similar to `await asyncio.sleep(0)`, or use multiprocessing instead of threading.

Answer (score 0):

I have [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74652408/python-asyncio-wait-for-doesnt-stop-after-given-timeout?noredirect=1#comment-131767905) the cause of the issue. You should remove or replace the `time.sleep` at `f1` as it blocks the thread, and `asyncio.wait_for` cannot handle the timeout.

Regarding to the `RuntimeWarning`

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'f1' was never awaited handle = None  # Needed to break cycles when an exception occurs.

It occurs because the [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) expects a non-async function as a second argument.

Comment: `time.sleep` in fact represents something that big numpy arrays are doing numerical computation.

Comment: `asyncio.sleep` represents several async disk IO operations

Comment: Then why are you trying to execute it in an event loop? Numpy calculations use much CPU underhood, and I cannot see the reason for trying to make them run asynchronously.

Comment: second part are some IO operations, like writing large model parameters into disk with some computation. I can did asynchronous

Comment: Ok but you cannot stop the thread while it is run see the answer Ahmed has shared in the comments of the other answer.